# Ubuntu Qmake is not an executable

Tags: linux-mint, qt, qtcreator

after installing new version of QtCreator in Ubuntu and

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake build-essential g++ gcc
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   build-essential is already the newest version.
   g++ is already the newest version.
   g++ set to manually installed.
   gcc is already the newest version.
   qt5-qmake is already the newest version.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 247 not upgraded.
```

in option of `Build & Run` and choose qmake in `/usr/bin/qmake` i get this error :

```
The qmake executable /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake could not be added: qmake '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake' is not an executable.
```

in Home system i don't have any problem after installing those packages and setting Qmake in option

Other information:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > apt-cache search qt5-qmake
qt5-qmake - Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool

tux-world@alachiq:~ > ldd /opt/qtForArm/bin/qmake 
     ldd: /opt/qtForArm/bin/qmake: No such file or directory

tux-world@alachiq:~ > sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
[sudo] password for tux-world: 
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake’: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > apt-cache policy qt5-qmake
qt5-qmake:
  Installed: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2
  Candidate: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages



tux-world@alachiq:~ > ls -a -l /usr/bin/qmake 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 فوریه 19 15:53 /usr/bin/qmake -> qtchooser



tux-world@alachiq:~ > qtchooser 
Usage:
  qtchooser { -l | -list-versions | -print-env }
  qtchooser -run-tool=<tool name> [-qt=<Qt version>] [program arguments]
  <executable name> [-qt=<Qt version>] [program arguments]

Environment variables accepted:
 QTCHOOSER_RUNTOOL  name of the tool to be run (same as the -run-tool argument)
 QT_SELECT          version of Qt to be run (same as the -qt argument)

tux-world@alachiq:~ >
```

Comment: Please give the output of `apt-cache policy qt5-qmake`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed qt5-qmake, but your Qt Creator is looking for the Qt4 version of qmake. You can either install qt4-qmake or add your Qt5 qmake executable to Qt Creator in Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> Qt Versions.

/edit after an update in the question:

Qt Chooser is a tool to automatically select the correct Qt binaries depending on its configuration and/or environment variables.

If you want to use the Qt 5 qmake, all you need to is installing the package `qt5-default`. That will point the various binaries (like `/usr/bin/qmake`) provided by Qt Chooser to your Qt 5 installation. If you want to use the Qt 4 qmake, you'll need to install `qt4-default`, which does the same thing, but for Qt 4.